# Removing " " in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF as shown below

```
DF =
Index   R
0       A
1       "B,C"
2       D
3       "E,F"
```

I want to remove all "" from the values:

```
DF_New =
Index   R
0       A
1       B,C
2       D
3       E,F
```

Using join(literal_eval(x)) or other constructions don't work. What should I do?

Comment: Do you *control* the DataFrame's *construction*?

Comment: `df.applymap(lambda x: x.strip('\"') if isinstance(x, str) else x)` if you want to drop double quotes along the entire df.

Comment: @wwii You were right. I had to construct it in another way. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) accessor:

```
>>> df['R'].str.replace('"', '')
0      A
1    B,C
2      D
3    E,F
Name: R, dtype: object
```

which should eliminate all literal double-quotes from that column.

Note that each result will be a `str` such as `'B,C'`.  If you want to convert each to a list container, use:

```
>>> df['R'].str.replace('"', '').str.split()
0      [A]
1    [B,C]
2      [D]
3    [E,F]
Name: R, dtype: object
```

Comment: Eh, this was the first thing I tried and it didn't do a thing. I mean even this did nothing ".replace('^"', '', regex=True).replace('"$', '', regex=True)"

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
DF.loc[DF['R'].str.startswith('"'), 'R'] = DF['R'].str[1:]
DF.loc[DF['R'].str.endswith('"'), 'R'] = DF['R'].str[:-1]
```

For example,

```
In [5]: DF
Out[5]: 
   Index      R
0      0      A
1      1  "B,C"
2      2      D
3      3  "E,F"

In [6]: DF.loc[DF['R'].str.startswith('"'), 'R'] = DF['R'].str[1:]
In [7]: DF.loc[DF['R'].str.endswith('"'), 'R'] = DF['R'].str[:-1]
In [8]: DF
Out[8]: 
   Index    R
0      0    A
1      1  B,C
2      2    D
3      3  E,F
```

Note that this will only replace double quotes that appear at the beginning or end of the string, not in the middle.